# How to estimate cost for a reserved vs On Demand EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, windows-10

I am new to AWS and I did not find any cost calculator for the below mentioned requirement.

2 instances of t2.xlarge (Quad-processor, 16GB RAM) with 100GB of SSD for a month. One on Ubuntu and other on windows 10. How can I check on the cost for On Demand as well as for Reserved instances

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: The cost calculator here is what you would use to calculate this: https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html however it doesn't have the new t2.xlarge instances listed yet. This is a third-party tool that does have t2.xlarge listed: http://www.ec2instances.info/?selected=t2.xlarge

Comment: Thanks that helps